# Adobe Analytics can't find Config file when using build flavours

Tags: android, android-build, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to get Adobe Analytics set up for an existing project. I have two build flavours that each have their own asset folder, but also a main project with it's own asset folder. In this asset folder I placed the correct config json file (literally copied from the working iOS version) and still I'm getting the following error:

```
ADBMobile Debug : Marketing Cloud - Not configured locally.
```

I've tried overriding the path to the config file using:

```
Config.overrideConfigStream(getAssets("configfilename"));
```

And I've also tried it with an actual file from a different location. If the path is not correct I get a 'File not found' error, but when it's correct I get the same error as above.

Anyone that can help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create assets folder per each flavor/build type combination.

Consider the case:

- you have 2 build types - debug and release
- you also have 2 flavors named ukraine and poland

Then your folder structure with configs should look this way:

```
src/polandDebug/assets/configfilename
src/polandRelease/assets/configfilename
src/ukraineDebug/assets/configfilename
src/ukraineRelease/assets/configfilename
```

configfilename is the name of your omniture configs json file.

In each assets folder config file have different ids defined for dev/prod builds per each flavor.